# What's wrong with my login process?

Tags: server, login, lightdm, ldap

- I installed and configured a test server with OpenLDAP and created a user with username (uid) "jdoe", following some of the guide at:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html.
- I used phpLDAPadmin to create my OUs and users.
- I installed and configured `libnss-ldap` per the guide.
- I can `su - jdoe` and it works okay.
- I configured `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to show a manual login.
- I could log in to Ubuntu graphically (with the LightDM greeter) as "jdoe", until changing jdoe's uid to 5000. I changed this because I noticed his and my uids were both set to 1000, which I think caused some weird issues. Now, when I try logging in graphically as jdoe, I get a sound and the screen flashes, but it does not log jdoe in to his Ubuntu desktop. I noticed when I create a new user in phpLDAPadmin, their uid defaults to 1000 - the same as my uid... Is this how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there is a setting in `/etc/phpldapadmin/config.php` of auto_number...

I set:
`$servers->setValue('auto_number','enable',true);`
`$servers->setValue('auto_number','mechanism','search');`
`$servers->setValue('auto_number','min',array('uidNumber'=>5000,'gidNumber'=>5000));`

I could then log in with both `su -` and via the graphical shell.